# A UIView isn't placed right on top of a collection view cell when inserted to the view controller view's hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview

I have a horizontal collection view, which cells don't cover the whole screen. I want to insert a `UIView` to a view controller's hierarchy and place it right on top of the selected cell.

In order to do that I need the frame of the selected cell. To get it I've tried the following inside the `didSelectItem` method:

**1)**

```
let frame = collectionViewLayout.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)?.frame
```

**2)**

```
 let selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
```

In both cases I get the same result and that's the right one. For inserting a `UIView` into the hierarchy I use the following code:

```
    self.view.insertSubview(mimicView, aboveSubview: collectionView)
    mimicView.frame = frame

    print ("mimicView frame:", mimicView.frame)
```

The print statement prints the right frame (it is the same as the one of the selected cell). However, `mimicView` position isn't exactly on top of the cell when it is drawn. For the first cell the `view`'s `y` has a small negative value. For the subsequent cells the `view` is drawn further and further to the left. So, for example, for the second cell, the `view` is drawn almost on top of the third one. And for the third one, it is drawn almost on top of the fifth one. In `Interface Debugger` I see that its `x` value is way too big and `y` value is a small negative number (like `-20` - `-40` points), however, the print statement still shows the same values as for the selected cell.

If someone knows why this is happening, I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you convert the cell's `bounds` to the view's coordinate system (the view to which you want to add the new subview) and use the resulting rectangle as your covering view's `frame`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) else { return }
    let cellFrame = cell.convert(cell.bounds, to: view)

    let coverView = UIView(frame: cellFrame)
    coverView.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    view.addSubview(coverView)
}
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple. Thanks for your help, it works!